# Error when combining datetime.date object with datetime.time object

Tags: python, sql, date, python-datetime

I am currently trying to combine a datetime.date object with a datetime.time object to get the resulting datetime.datetime style object.

I run an SQL query and parse the results by doing the following:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('stu.sqlite3', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT intra_day.date, intra_day.time, intra_day.price, closing_price.date, closing_price.cprice FROM intra_day, closing_price WHERE intra_day.date = closing_price.date')

for row in cur:
    date_intra, time_intra, price_intra, cp_date, cprice = (row[0], row[1], float(row[2]), row[3], float(row[4]))
    date_intra = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_intra, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').date()
    time_intra = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_intra, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    cp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(cp_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').date()
```

Once that has run, and I run the type and print tests in the IDLE i get the following:

```
type(date_intra)
Out[2]: datetime.date

type(time_intra)
Out[3]: datetime.time

type(cp_date)
Out[4]: datetime.date

print date_intra, time_intra, price_intra, cp_date, cprice
2008-07-07 05:40:00 1265.5 2008-07-07 1251.75

date_intra, time_intra, price_intra, cp_date, cprice
Out[13]: 
(datetime.date(2008, 7, 7),
 datetime.time(5, 40),
 1265.5,
 datetime.date(2008, 7, 7),
 1251.75)
```

So from that, it all looks like I should be able to use:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(date_intra(), time_intra())
```

to combine the date object and the time object but i get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not callable
```

Because I am not great with Python I also tried:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(date_intra), datetime.time(time_intra))
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Could anyone point out to me what i am doing wrong and perhaps correct me?

Once I have combined those two (date_intra and time_intra) I wish to combine cp_date with time_intra.

Comment: Have you tried `datetime.datetime.combine(date_intra, time_intra)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in the date and time objects *directly*:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(date_intra, time_intra)
```

These are *already* the correct type of objects that `datetime.combine()` expects; there is no need to call them or to cast them to the correct type *again*.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_intra = datetime.date(2008, 7, 7)
>>> time_intra = datetime.time(5, 40)
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(date_intra, time_intra)
datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 7, 5, 40)
```

You could just parse the time and date *in one step*:

```
date_intra, time_intra, price_intra, cp_date, cprice = (row[0], row[1], float(row[2]), row[3], float(row[4]))
intra = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    '{} {}'.format(date_intra.partition(' ')[0], time_intra),
    '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

This takes the date portion of the `date_intra` string (everything before the first space) and appends the `time_intra` column text to that to parse out a combined date and time.

Comment: That's great - thank you both for the answers!! I'm teaching myself this stuff from scratch and it melts my brain sometimes - your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is

```
datetime.datetime.combine(date_intra(), time_intra())
```

This is where you're treating two variables, `date_intra` and `time_intra` as functions, and you're trying to *call* them. Remove the parentheses:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(date_intra, time_intra)
datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 7, 5, 40)
```

Comment: That's great - thank you both for the answers!! I'm teaching myself this stuff from scratch and it melts my brain sometimes - your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, please accept either of the two answers and upvote if you found them helpful.